# How to send arbitrary parameters to controller using simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm building a newsletter management form and I want to use simple_form. The `email` parameter should be sent to the `email_subscriber#manage` controller/action via `POST` method.

**routes.rb**

```
get 'email/login' => 'email_subscribers#login', as: 'email_login'
get 'email/manage' => 'email_subscribers#manage', as: 'email_manage'
```

**email_subscribers_controller.rb**

```
def login

end

def manage
    @subscriber = EmailSubscriber.find_by_email(safe_params(:email))

    unless @subscriber
        # redirect_to email_login_path, notice: 'That email does not exist.'
    end
end
```

**email/login form**

```
<%= render :layout => 'application/container' do %>
    <%= simple_form_for(@subscriber, path: :email_manage_path, method: :get) do |f| %>
            <%= f.error_notification %>

            <div class="form-inputs">
                <%= f.input :email, as: :email %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-actions">
                <%= f.button :submit, value: 'Manage Subscription' %>
            </div>
    <% end %>
```

The login route is where the form is. It allows the user to enter their email in order to unsubscribe from the newsletter.

The form should redirect to the `manage` action, passing the `email` parameter for which there is no corresponding model.

The current form doesn't work. For some reason it redirects to the `EmailSubscribers` index page.
Changing the `email_manage` route to `POST` causes `missing route POST email/login` which makes no sense because the form is posting to `email_manage_path`, not the `email_login_path`

Thanks

EDIT:

**rake routes output (opens in this same tab)**

http://pastebin.com/eFGdvxid

Comment: can you post your routes? `rake routes`

Comment: Added a pastebin with the full `rake routes` output

Answer (score 0):

You can actually model this as a conventional RESTful resource instead:

```
resources :subscriptions
namespace :subscriptions do
  resources :logins
  get '/login', to: 'logins/create'
end
```

The advantage is that you get a much simpler setup that follows the canonical crud verbs and you also use the correct HTTP verbs.

The only unconventional part here is that we add an additional route to `create` via GET:

```
# app/controllers/subscriptions/logins_controller.rb
class Subscriptions::LoginsController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActionController::ParameterMissing, with: :subscription_not_found

  # GET /subscriptions/logins/new
  def new
    @subscription = Subscription.new
  end

  # POST /subscriptions/logins
  # GET /subscriptions/login
  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.find_by_email(email_param)
    if @subscription
      redirect_to edit_subscription_path(@subscription)
    else
      subscription_not_found
    end
  end

  private

  def subscription_not_found
    render :new, error: 'Email could not be found.'
  end

  def email_param
    if request.post?
      params.require(:subscription).fetch(:email)
    else
      params.fetch(:email)
    end
  end
end
```

Since we actually are binding to a resource you can set the form up in a very straight forward way. We also add a GET route which lets the user log in directly from a link.

The form is very straight forward.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@subscription, path: subscriptions_sessions_path) do %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, as: :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, value: 'Manage Subscription' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You can then create a pretty run of the mill CRUD controller that lets the user edit or unsubscribe:

```
# app/controllers/subscriptions_controller.rb
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_subscription, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_email

  def new
    @subscription = Subscription.new
  end

  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)
    if @subscription.save(subscription_params)
      redirect_to root_path, success: 'Your subscription settings have been creates'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @subscription.update(subscription_params)
      redirect_to root_path, success: 'Your subscription settings have been updated'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @subscription.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private 

  def set_subscription
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
  end

  def subscription_params
    params.require(:subscription).permit(:foo, :bar, :baz)
  end
end
```

Comment: i needed some time to let that sink in. Doesn't answer the question technically as I'd still like to know how use simple_form without a model, but i do like your approach. very clever! Integrating your answer into my app now.

Comment: You can use it without a table backed model by creating a "virtual" model that includes `ActiveModel::Model` or you just use the plain old rails tag helpers to create input elements. SF is not built to work without a model.

Comment: Also its a good idea to create tokens which you send out in emails instead of using the users email as a parameter. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SecureToken/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Why does the `/login` route go to `sessions#create`? shouldnt it go to `logins#create`?